# Brute force (exact) algorithm for Vertex Cover

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, approximation, np-complete

Can someone provide a detailed algorithm to implement a brute force (exact) algorithm for vertex cover. Currently, I know how to find a vertex cover using a log(n)-Approximation Algorithm, but cannot figure out how to go about the brute force.

```
log(n)-Approximation Algorithm

SmartGreedyVertexCover(G)
Input: A graph G.
Output: A set of vertices that form a (not necessarily optimal) vertex cover.
1:C←∅
2:while G has at least one edge do
3:  v←vertex in G with maximum degree
4:  G←G\v (This also removes all edges adjacent to v)
5:  C←C∪v
6:return C
```

Comment: The most brute-force solution is to try all subsets of vertices, and then pick the smallest that covers all edges

Comment: The algorithm in [this paper](https://www.cs.lafayette.edu/~gexia/research/mfcs06.pdf) by Chen, Kanj, and Xia probably scales the best.